# Doing a retag results in full edit-like behaviour

Tags: support, retagging

I have issues with retagging.

1. For the last few days I couldn't retag as part of the Tag Cleanup (which is some sort of zen exercise for me, so imagine my frustration). I'd always get a "not substantial enough" edit warning. I wrote in Chat about it and was sent here. (BTW, I'm working on [server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/server). Help is appreciated.)
2. Now, as of today, I can retag, but it appears to count as an edit, which is not desirable (I don't mind the points, but the mods will certainly not be happy about it.)

On a sidenote, it would be nice to have the Retag button back, why was it removed in the first place? (Edit: I bow to the majority's opinion.)

**Edit**: I still have the problem. Now I can't even retag anymore without triggering the 6-character warning. (Body and title left unchanged.)

**Edit2**: Problem's still there. [Can I install two versions (1.4 and 1.6) of svnserve and configure it to run simultaneously on a single host?](https://superuser.com/questions/111872/can-i-install-two-versions-1-4-and-1-6-of-svnserve-and-configure-it-to-run-sim) Tag edits possible, but results in full edit.

**Edit3:** So, the problem's still there. Last warning: If no one does anything about it, I'll just go on retagging and get credits for it.

Just out of curiosity: Can anyone here do anything about it? If not, who do I talk to?

Comment: As I read it, there's no retag privilege anymore. You're doing full edits now, so please make them substantial enough. Sathya's answer is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per

[Kill the Retag option, use just Edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/kill-the-retag-option-use-just-edit) & [Propose a privilege to sit in the 500 reputation mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/propose-a-privilege-to-sit-in-the-500-reputation-mark)

retag is no longer present.

> As determined from earlier discussions, the retag privilege serves a lot more confusion and a lot less of its benefit due to the suggested edit system. It must be done away with. It **will** be done away with. ♪

So this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: This isn't by-design. *> I can retag, but it appears to count as an edit, which is not desirable (I don't mind the points, but the mods will certainly not be happy about it.)* – it shouldn't count as a suggested edit, [but it does](http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/126167). Oded said that *"having the retag questions privilege will make it a regular edit"*.

Comment: @slhck looking back some related questions - does seem to be a bug

Comment: @slhck looks like the privilege has been revoked.

Comment: Ah. Interesting. (NB: how are moderators ever going to know that stuff without browsing MSO all day long? `</rant>`)

Comment: @slhck don't get me started - was as clueless was you. Long standing grouse..